# Java "ClassNotFoundException" canonical question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

I meet each day dozens of similar questions where people claim about `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` in java.

Just recent examples:

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273697/java-lang-classnotfoundexceptionorg-apache-tika-sax-bodycontenthandler)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273799/classnotfoundexception-in-httpclient-api

In most cases it looks like that people have deep misunderstanding of principles about linking libraries, building and running jars with classpath.

I consider all such questions as duplicates, but I'm not sure which question should be considered as "mother" question in this case. I've thought it is 
[What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)

but I'm not sure on 100%. There is also [How do I resolve this Java Class not found exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-this-java-class-not-found-exception) question, but it is also has quite pure explaining of steps for solving this problem.

I believe we need something like this question: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for `ClassNotFoundException` case.

So, I'm looking for authoritative community advice, what question use for such cases for closing them as duplicates?

<strike>**UPD**: I've also created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274603/program-works-from-ide-but-when-running-it-outside-ide-i-receive-classnotfound question for this purpose.</strike>

Comment: If a question already exists, why do we need another one? If you want to provide information that's not already there, add another answer to the question; if you want to highlight a particular answer when marking it duplicate, add a comment.

Comment: Existent questions are very broad, I'm suggesting more typical and practical case

Comment: Also, @AndyTurner, it is not constructive approach. I've asked here very clear question: which question use as canonical. I'm not obliged to create canonical *answer* in case if I can not find it.

Comment: "I've also created ... question for this purpose" is what I was specifically saying was unnecessary. I see that you've now deleted it, so...

Comment: Ok, but you have downvoted this particular meta question (haven't you?). Was is the reason? I asked incorrect question here about canonical question? Or what?

Comment: I considered your proposal to create another question not to be useful. You've now removed it, so, downvote removed.